# mergePromise(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I run the code, I get the error

> mergePromise(...).then is not a function.

I want to know why I got this error.

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, ms);
});

const ajax1 = () => timeout(2000).then(() => {
    console.log('1');
    return 1;
});

const ajax2 = () => timeout(1000).then(() => {
    console.log('2');
    return 2;
});

const ajax3 = () => timeout(2000).then(() => {
    console.log('3');
    return 3;
});

const mergePromise = ajaxArray => {
    const data=[];
    ajaxArray[0]().then(i=>data.push(i));
    timeout(1005).then(() => {
        ajaxArray[1]().then(i=>data.push(i));
    });
    timeout(10).then(() => {
        ajaxArray[2]().then(i=>data.push(i));
    });
    return data;
};
```

I guess maybe the timeout function has some mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mergePromise` does not return a `Promise`.

Comment: Read [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: to clarify the first comment, `const data = []` - obviously, `data` is an `Array` ... `return data` - you're returning an `Array` - simples, arrays don't have a `.then` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `return Promise.resolve(data)` instead, it would return a promise, which is what you need.